# Shortcut for assigning attributes from __init__

Tags: python

I quite often find myself directly assigning a class' attributes from values passed to the __init__:

```py
class SomeThing:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d, e ...):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        ...
```

Is there some way to streamline this?

Answer (score 2):

[Dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) are designed especially for this kind of `__init__` functions.

With them you can write your class like this:

```
@dataclass
class SomeThing:
    a: int
    b: str
    c: float
    d: bool
    e: list

    # __init__ will be generated automatically based on fields declaration above
```

Comment: Note, dataclasses do a lot more than this, so it may not be an appropriate use-case.